# Should I use mutable priority queue for dikjstra/A* algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, path-finding

I am trying to implement A* algorithm and Dikjstra algorithm as a special case of A* (just pass `h(x){return 0;}` to A*), when choosing the priority_queue, I have two choices

1. use an empty priority_queue, and push start point when initializing, and do  "pop u, push neighbors of u satisfying certain conditions", in this
   way, one node might be pushed twice if it is a common neighbor of
   two other nodes.
2. use a mutable priority queue that supports
   `update()/decreaseKey()/increaseKey()`, I could choose data
   structures  in `boost::heap` or I could (actually I have) implement a
   priority_queue by myself, in this way, all nodes are needed to be pushed    to the container when initializing and handles for them need to be kept.

what are the pros and cons of these two strategies and which one is more practical?

Answer (score 0):

A common implementation of a priority queue for Dijkstra's in C++ uses `std::set`, where the smallest item is `set.begin()`, and you can `find` an exact item and `erase` it. You can also easily define a facade which allows to access `std::set` with a priority queue-like interface and support the additional update/erase/increaseKey/decreaseKey methods.

Look here for code samples for Dijkstra's implementations with both `std::set` and `std::priority_queue`: https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/power-up-c-with-the-standard-template-library-part-2/#dijkstra2

This article also makes a claim, that the performance is naturally the same, whether you use `std::priority_queue` and discard stale items you've popped, or you use `std::set` and erase the old item immediately.

Comment: If I use `std::set`, and use `std::pair<NodeIdx, NodeValue>` to represent the node in graph, and define a function compare  nodevalues of two node, then it is still possible two have two items representing same node in the set, for example, `pair<NodeIdx = 3, NodeValue = 4>` and pari<NodeIdx = 3, NodeIdx = 5>`

Comment: @Alaya Did you look at the code? You have to manually delete the previous one. Also it's better to use `std::pair<NodeValue, NodeIdx>` for automatic sorting.

Comment: I think even if you don't delete the previous version of the data, the algorithm won't go wrong, because the newly inserted data always have a smaller value.